# SSIS Reading Data From Excel Fails on Second Data Flow

Tags: ssis

I have 2 excel files with 2 tabs holding data on them.
I need to load data from both the tabs of these excel files into a stage table, hence i have created 4 data flow tasks in SSIS to import data from these 4 Excel Tabs into 4 stage tables.

I am getting random failures for the second set of data flows, where the DFT simply fails without any error code.
The first set of data flows which read data from the first tabs of the same excel files run properly, but the second set of data flows which are reading data off the second tab of the excel files are where i am seeing this failure.

Any suggestions/thoughts on the possible reasons would be appreciated.
[Package Stuck on Second Set of DFT's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6HswG.jpg)

Thanks & Regards,
Suvrat

Comment: check data of 2nd tab is not consistent

Answer (score 0):

When you make a connection to excel file in dataflow(1), you will lock the excel file. (excel will be locked) till the connection finish or terminated.

you should perpare 4 dataflows for 4 tabs in 2 excel. each dataflow will terminate the connection after the job completes.

Answer (score 0):

If you have 4 different data flows using the same connections manager then you would also need to make sure that your flow is correct. have you connected the data flows in a way where one is finished and only then the next starts?